# How much does mandrake root cost?

Tags: dnd-5e, pricing

I'm interested in making a homunculus, but they require mandrake root to make them, and I can't find the price of it anywhere, so does anyone have any idea of how much it costs?

Comment: [Related] [How can I create a Homunculus?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/76638)

Answer (score 21):

## Mandrake is a common plant of no particular value

[Mandrake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandrake) is a common flower (in many parts of Europe).

There is no indication that this material component should be any pricier, or harder to find, than the other materials in the list. Heck, it’s in the *middle* of a list of common materials. Compare it to mistletoe, the material component of the *Goodberry* spell.

Mandrake root has been attributed with mystical powers in superstitions and various fantasy stories. But there’s no indication in the D&D rules that it should be less common than it is in the real world.

### Xanathar’s Guide, *Create Homunculus* spell

*Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* includes *Create Homonculus* as a spell, which lists mandrake root as a component with no gold-piece value. Mandrake root is listed alongside clay and ash. Contrariwise, in a separate clause, another component is listed with a gold-piece value.

### Without *Xanathar’s*

The rest of the answer is older material, which might still be useful if your DM doesn’t use *Xanather’s Guide to Everything*

The *Monster Manual* provides general guidance on how to create a homunculus, without providing an actual mechanic.

If the DM determines there is a regular **spell** to create the homunculus, then RAW, “a character can use a **component pouch** or **spellcasting focus**...in place of the components” (PH, p. 203: **Components**).

Answer (score 20):

### There is no Official Source

It's not priced anywhere in the PHB, MM, or DMG, meaning that it would be completely up to your DM.

If your DM is feeling generous, they may say that a component pouch includes it. Alternatively they might have you forage for it.

### Your DM may Still Disallow it

MM pg. 188

> Shaping a mixture of clay, ash, mandrake root, and blood, one can channel rare ritual magic to create a faithful, squirrel-sized companion.

Your DM may rule that you do not have access to the 'rare ritual magic'.

Essentially, as this is part of the MM, not the PHB, it is well within DM purview. Your first course of action should be to speak to them about it.

Comment: There is an official source: Xanthar's Guide to Everything lists Mandrake root as a material component with no gold piece value for the Create Homonculus spell. Therefore, a Spell Component Pouch can be used in its place (or an Arcane Focus). No DM generosity is required to say that a component pouch includes it. (This answer was posted before Xanthar's was available, so accurate at the time, but should be updated)

Comment: @TimC The consens is that a spellcasting focus cannot replace consumed components. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138807/can-a-spell-focus-or-component-pouch-be-used-with-a-spell-that-has-costless-cons