# Does a level 20 druid bypass the costless but consumed mistletoe material component of the spell Druid Grove?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, druid, spell-components

The spell *Druid Grove* has an oddly specific material component that is consumed but is otherwise costless: "A mistletoe harvested with a golden sickle under the light of a full moon" (XGE, p.154).

At level 20, an Arcdruid can ignore material components that don't have a cost **and** aren't consumed (PHB, p.64).

Does that mean that the druid can ignore material components that have no cost but **are** consumed?

Just have this idea of a high-level naked druid wandering in the forests creating temporary sanctuaries all over. But I don't know whether the druid itself has to have the component for *Druid Grove* on hand, or can just be completely naked.

Comment: It seems like you're answering your own question here -- you quote the relevant rule and then ask if the relevant rule *really* means it?  What's the alternative interpretation of the rule that wouldn't lead to needing the specific component?

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I think part of the question is how to read the natural language boolean logic.

Answer (score 11):

### No. The Archdruid feature does not allow you to ignore material components that are consumed.

Archdruid states:

> Additionally, you can ignore the verbal and somatic components of your druid spells, as well as any material components that lack a cost **and** aren’t consumed by a spell.

Use of the word “and” indicates you can ignore a material component only if both the following are true:

- it has no cost
- it is not consumed

The material component for *druid grove* is:

> *mistletoe, **which the spell consumes**, that was harvested with a golden sickle under the light of a full moon*

Since the mistletoe is consumed, it must be provided - it cannot be ignored with the Archdruid feature.

Comment: Perhaps of note is a construction that would allow this: "any material components that lack a cost and any material components that aren’t consumed by a spell.". Better even: just changing "and" to "or" in the original

Comment: A useful mnemonic for this is that if a druid could cast a spell with a druidic focus in place of the material components, then an archdruid can cast that same spell with no material component.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson That is flat out incorrect! The spellcasting focus rules care ONLY about whether or not the component has a cost, whereas the feature is stricter, requiring a component that neither has a cast nor is consumed.

Comment: @vonBoomslang A focus cannot replace a cost-free-but-consumed material component. See here: [Can a Spell Focus or Component Pouch be used with a spell that has costless consumed components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138807)